# Generate all combinations for pair of bits set to 1?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, combinations, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to generate all possible combinations for pair of 1's within given bit width.

Let's say the bit width is 6, i.e. number 32. This is what I would like to generate:

```
000000
000011
000110
001100
001111
011000
011011
011110
110000
110011
110110
111100
111111
```

If I have variables:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2;
    num = a | b;
```

and create a loop that I'll loop over `width - 1` times, and where I shift both `a << 1` and `b << 1`, I'll get all combinations for one pair. After that, I'm pretty much stuck.

Could someone , please, provide some help.

**Update: working example**
Based on Barmar's mathematical approach, this is what I managed to implement

```
var arr = [],
    arrBits = [];

function getCombs(pairs, startIdx) {
    var i, j, val = 0, tmpVal, idx;

    if (startIdx + 2 < pairs) {
        startIdx = arr.length - 1;
        pairs -= 1;
    }

    if (pairs < 2) {
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < pairs-1; i++) {
        idx = startIdx - (i * 2);
        val += arr[idx];

    }

    for (j = 0; j < idx - 1; j++) {
        arrBits.push((val + arr[j]).toString(2));
    }

    getCombs(pairs, startIdx-1);
}

(function initArr(bits) {
    var i, val, pairs, startIdx;

    for (i = 1; i < bits; i++) {
        val = i == 1 ? 3 : val * 2;
        arr.push(val);
        arrBits.push(val.toString(2));
    }

    pairs = Math.floor(bits / 2);
    startIdx = arr.length - 1;

    getCombs(pairs, startIdx);
    console.log(arrBits);

}(9));
```

**Working example on JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/zywc5/

Comment: Your combination list is missing a lot of combinations. Like 000001. In fact, if you want all combination of 0 and 1 and width 6, you should have 64 possible combinations. Is your list a sample only or there's something else that you are not saying?

Comment: 1 doesn't have a pair of 1's. Based on his example, he's looking for all bit sequences that contain an even number of pairs of adjacent 1's.

Comment: As I stated on my question I wanted only `all possible combinations for pair of 1's`... so single 1's hanging there somewhere are not allowed

Comment: Do you have to do it using bitwise operators? There's a simple algebraic solution.

Comment: @Barmar if there's a mathematical solution for this, I'm all ears... I guess it will actually suit me better than bits. I didn't see any relation what it comes to those numbers.

Comment: I got it now. Let me think. =p

Comment: @lolol take your time, whenever you're ready! :)

Comment: @micadelli, in case you find a solution, place it here ;)

Comment: @devundef Sure I will - working on Barmar's suggestion.

Comment: @devundef After struggling many hours, I managed to get a working code. See my question for working example.

Comment: @micadelli, these 1's pairs seems a little trick (I like trick codes + solution). Nice work!

Comment: @micadelli But your code gives `[11,110,1100,11000,110000,1100000,11000000,110000000,111111011,111111110,11111111,111100011,111100110,111101100,111111000,11110011,11110110,11111100,1111011,1111110,111111,110000011,110000110,110001100,110011000,110110000,111100000,11000011,11000110,11001100,11011000,11110000,1100011,1100110,1101100,1111000,110011,110110,111100,11011,11110,1111]`. This isn't what you wanted, isn't it? My answer gives the exact result that you posted above...

Comment: @Oriol yes, both of our code gives the same results - order does not matter and I can sort the array anyway... and I like the mathematical approach more (although not tested, I think it's faster). I suck at recursive functions so I think it could easily be made to work more efficiently.

Comment: @micadelli I meant that `arrBits`'s elements have different lengths:  `arrBits[0]` has 2 digits, `arrBits[1]` 3, `arrBits[2]` 4... I don't understand the relationship between `arrBits` and what you asked.

Comment: @Oriol in this case arrBits is only for printing those numbers in strings as 1's and 0's... in real case it's for real integer values, e.g. 100000 = 32. So, in real code the array would look like `3, 6, 9, 12...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers with exactly one pair of 1's are the sequence 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, ...; they start with 3 and just double each time.

The numbers with two pairs of 1's are 12+3, 24+3, 24+6, 48+3, 48+6, 48+12, ...; these are the above sequence starting at 12 + the original sequence up to n/4.

The numbers with three pairs of 1's are 48+12+3, 96+12+3, 96+24+3, 96+24+6, ...

The relationship between each of these suggests a recursive algorithm making use of the original doubling sequence. I don't have time right now to write it, but I think this should get you going.

Comment: Edit! I think I got it now. My grey cells are slow on these kind of mathematical problems.

Answer (score 0):

if the bit width isn't that big then you'll be way better off creating bit representations for all numbers from 0 to 31 in a loop and simply ignore the ones that have an odd number of "ones" in the bit representation.

Comment: How should I validate the number doesn't have a single 1?

Comment: This isn't a list of all numbers with even hamming weight though - for example 101 isn't in it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start counting normally in binary and replace all 1's with 11's like this:

```
n = 5
n = n.toString(2)          //= "101"
n = n.replace(/1/g, "11")  //= "11011"
n = parseInt(n, 2)         //= 27
```

So you'll get:

```
0   -> 0
1   -> 11
10  -> 110
11  -> 1111
100 -> 1100
101 -> 11011
110 -> 11110
111 -> 111111
```

And so on. You'll have to count up to 31 or so on the left side, and reject ones longer than 6 bits on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/SBH6R/

```
var len=6,
    arr=[''];
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
        var k=j;
        if(getNum1(arr[j])%2===1){
            arr[j]+=1;
        }else{
            if(i<len-1){
                arr.splice(j+1,0,arr[j]+1);
                j++;
            }
            arr[k]+=0;
        }      
    }
}
function getNum1(str){
    var n=0;
    for(var i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(str.substr(i,1)==='1'){n++;}
        else{break;}
    }
    return n;
}
document.write(arr.join('<br />'));
```

Or maybe you will prefer http://jsfiddle.net/SBH6R/1/. It's simpler, but then you will have to `sort()` the array:

```
var len=6,
    arr=[''];
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    for(var k=0,l=arr.length;k<l;k++){
        if(getNum1(arr[k])%2===1){
            arr[k]+=1;
        }else{
            if(i<len-1){
                arr.push(arr[k]+1);
            }
            arr[k]+=0;
        }     
    }
}
function getNum1(str){
    var n=0;
    for(var i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(str.substr(i,1)==='1'){n++;}
        else{break;}
    }
    return n;
}
document.write(arr.sort().join('<br />'));
```

See http://jsperf.com/generate-all-combinations-for-pair-of-bits-set-to-1 if you want to compare the performance. It seems that the fastest code is the first one on Chrome but the second one on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with bit twiddling. If the lowest two bits are zero, we need to set them, which is equivalent to adding 3. Otherwise, we need to replace the lowest block of ones by its top bit and a 1-bit to the left of it. This can be done as follows, where `x` is the current combination:

```
x3 = x + 3;
return (((x ^ x3) - 2) >> 2) + x3;
```